# Composer error in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php

I was trying to create new Laravel 5.2 project by using composer in my terminal

theodory@theodory-SATELLITE-C50-B:~$ composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel shopping, and I final got this error how can I fix it?

> ->  "Segmentation fault (core dumped)"

Anyone with solution for this error it driving me cryz

Comment: Did you already try 'composer dump-autoload' + 'composer update'?

Comment: nothing is working by using composer when am trying to use any composer method it is giving me the same error

Comment: i think it have been caused because i was not in home directory and i was trying to create new project in another partition out of home directory when i came back to create in home directory it return that error, and i read in many articles on the internet that this problem is caused by trying to access memory space which can not be accessed any idea how i can solve this

Comment: Have your tried reinstalling composer? Also, try running command with maximum verbosity `-vvv`. Might display more details.

Comment: Most likely a problem in any of the packages. Comment providers and verify.

Answer (score 0):

Remove or disable xdebug to solve this

**Disable**
Find your php.ini and look for XDebug.
Set xdebug autostart to false

```
xdebug.remote_autostart=0  
xdebug.remote_enable=0
```

**OR**
**Remove**

```
sudo apt remove php-xdebug
```